# DESede/3DES ECB Encrypt/Decrypt on Windows Phone 8 with C#

Tags: encryption, windows-phone-8, bouncycastle, des

I'm looking for a way to encrypt a string with cipher **"DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding"** on **windows phone 8**.

Unlike Win8 RT, there isn't *SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider*.

I tried to add a BounceCastle c# library, as suggested [here](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2012/03/27/TripleDes-Encryption-with-Key-and-IV-for-Windows-Phone.aspx), but it seems that there isn't cipher "DESede/ECB/", but only "DESede/CBC/" with IV Key, while i want **ECB without IV key**.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks :)

**EDIT:** Solution with BounceCastle library:

```
// DESEDE, not DESEDE/CBC!!!
var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("DESEDE");
byte[] byte_key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string_key);
var param_key = new DesEdeParameters(byte_key);
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string_data);
cipher.Init(true, param_key);
var data_encrypted = cipher.DoFinal(data);
```

Comment: Any reason why you want really bad encryption?

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes, a valid reason. I need this. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is 3DES Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt cipher with PKCS#5 padding, and it should be supported by BouncyCastle (search for 3DES ECB).
Also it is supported by SecureBlackbox library (however, it is commercial).

Comment: d'oh, I had not watched carefully. Thanks ... edit on first post ASAP! ;)